# Make Visual Studio debugger auto refresh an Angular 6 application like ng serve

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I've got a Visual Studio solution containing a `.NET Web API` project as well as an `Angular 6` project. I'd like to be able to run the Visual Studio debugger on the Angular app and have it auto refresh on changes to the Angular code just like `ng serve` would do. Is there a way to do this, or similar, in `Visual Studio Professional 2015` or `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out. I think I know what you talking about. It can reload the page after you make changes. 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BrowserReloadonSave